# character entity names showing up on pdf

Tags: php, pdf, encoding, utf-8, fpdf

So i have text saved in the database that was inputed using a text editor, so it has some html in it, like `<p></p>` and such. this is easy, i just strip_tags(). my problem is the character entity names for special characters like &\nbsp; and &\ccedil; and &\otilde;
i need them to show up normally on the pdf but what i get is this:

"Ap&\oacute;s a visita do nosso t&\eacute;cnico, em anexo enviamos a nossa estimativa, como solicitado.
Para mais informa&\ccedil;&\otilde;es sobre as nossas Condi&\ccedil;&\otilde;es e Servi&\ccedil;os, por favor visite o
nosso site"

(never mind the "\", i had to put that in so that the character entity names would show up here)

i've tried multiple ways to convert this text:

1. strip_tags(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', htmlentities($text))))
2. strip_tags(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', htmlspecialchars($text)))
3. strip_tags(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode($text)))
4. strip_tags(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode(htmlentities($text))))

i've even found a function that converts ASCII characters with a for loop but this doesn't work for the cases where there's an entity name instead of the number:

strip_tags(str_ireplace('&\nbsp;',',convertASCIIToChar($text)))

```
function convertASCIIToChar($str){
$parts = preg_split("/\#(\d+)/",$str,NULL,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$count = count($parts);
for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i += 2) {
    $parts[$i] = chr($parts[$i]);
}
$str = implode($parts);
return $str;
}
```

it still just gives me the above text and doesn't convert it. i was thinking maybe a str_ireplace with 2 arrays associating the entity name to the character or something like that?

Edit: this is php and i'm using fpdf for the pdf part

Comment: Which language is this? Please add a suitable tag like [tag:php]

Comment: Also indicate the library used for creating the PDF.

Comment: can someone please help? i'm pretty sure it's as simple as calling the right function